# getApplicationLabel returns incorrect label

Tags: android

I used following code to find application label using package name.

```
mPackageManager.getApplicationLabel(mPackageManager
                .getApplicationInfo("com.android.vending",
                        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
```

"com.android.vending" is package name of play store app. This code returns "Google Play Store"  whereas the label on the device displays "Play Store". This happens with all Google apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code returns "Google Play Store" whereas the label on the device displays "Play Store".

That depends upon where you are looking for this label. The application label, on a device, is primarily used in the Settings app, in the list of installed applications. There, on a Nexus 4, the Play Store shows up as "Google Play Store".

"Play Store", by contrast, appears for things like the launcher icon. That is because the launcher icon label is not necessarily the same as the application label. The launcher icon label comes from the activity associated with that launcher icon. While by default the activity's label is the same as the application's label, developers are welcome to have these be separate. Google apparently has done so.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is there any way to find launcher icon label programmatically?

Comment: @SorryBoss: An app may have zero, one, or several activities in the launcher. If you only want the one "best" launcher, use `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` on `PackageManager`. To find all such activities, use `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager`. From there, you can call `loadLabel()` on an `ActivityInfo` or `ResolveInfo`.